# What the author of commits is supposed to do with the author date on history rewriting (Git)?

Tags: git, version-control

I saw many questions about *how to fiddle around with **author dates** and **committer dates*** when rebasing and/or squashing, but I don't grasp the *why* yet.

It seems to be clear that whether another person is applying a commit on behalf of its author, the committer information will be differentiated (actually, that person is not rewriting anything). *What about rewriting the history of a local (own) branch before pushing it into the remote repository?*

The author has several options:

- Modifying the author date to match the committer date.
- Modifying the commiter date to keep it the same as the author date.
- Do nothing.

Consider something like this:

[image]

Obviously, the default rebase will make both dates diverge in the rebased commits (and commits ahead can have older author dates!). The squash will create a completely new commit. I don't care about keeping it pretty, but, is this meaningful? *What are in this case the semantics of both dates?*

Thanks in advance.

Update:

With 'semantics', I mostly meant the 'intention conveyed'. I expect different tools behaving differently anyways, but what other Git users can expect from these two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself has no semantics for dates.  Well, *almost* none.  So it's really up to you.  Mostly, Git just shows you the commits with the author date visible.  If you use `git log --pretty=fuller`, it shows you the commits with both sets of dates visible, and that's it.

The one exception to this rule occurs whenever Git has *more than one commit in its grubby protuberances*.  The `git log` command can only show you one commit at a time, but you have—for some reason, and in some way—told it to show you *two or more* commits.  For instance, suppose you have this:

```
       C--D   <-- br1
      /
...--B
      \
       E--F   <-- br2
```

and you run `git log br1 br2` or `git log --all`.  You've just told Git: *Show me commits `D` and `F`, and then keep working backwards from there to show me earlier commits.*  Which one shall Git show now, `D`, or `F`?  It has a choice of two.

What Git does by default at this point is to pick the one with the *later committer date*.  This is a bit unfortunate since the date it shows you by default is the *author date*.  But it's up to you to make of it whatever you like.

The `git log` command has numerous options to *change* which of `D` or `F` it picks to show first.  These include `--author-date-order` and `--topo-order`.

Once Git *has* shown either `D` or `F`, it puts either `C` or `E` into the list.  That is, it puts into the list the parent of the one it showed.  Now the list says *either* `C F` *or* `D E`.  As before, it picks one—according to whichever rule-set you told it to use—and shows that.  The parent of `C` or `D` is `B` so if it just showed either of those, now `B` is in the list.  This repeats over and over again until the list shrinks down to just one entry—which tends to happen quickly since the rules tend to favor finishing up the `C-D` and `E-F` chains before moving back to `B`.  Moreover, some of the rules, such as `--topo-order`, tell Git that it *must* make that happen, *even if the date on `B` is weird*.

If you find Git listing things in weird orders, use `git log --graph` (perhaps also with `--oneline`).  The `--graph` option tells `git log` two things:

1. Draw a crude ASCII-based text graph of the commit log.  It's oriented vertically, rather than horizontally like I usually do in StackOverflow postings, but for simple-ish graphs or graph fragments, this works out fine.
2. Use `--topo-order` when doing the graph-walk.  That is, once Git has started down the `C-D` leg, it will *finish* that leg *before* starting the `E-F` leg.

(You can override the implied `--topo-order` with, e.g., `--date-order` or `--author-date-order`.)

#### You often see this sort of nonlinear behavior at merges

Note that, regardless of any commit date ordering, if Git has in its paws just *one* commit—if you said, for instance, `git log br1` so that Git starts at `D`—it just shows that one commit.  This empties out its list of commits to show, then puts `D`'s parent into the list.  The list now lists `C`, so Git shows `C`, which empties the list, but puts `B` into the list.  So now Git shows `B`, which empties the list, but puts `B`'s parent in, and so on.  The result is a simple, linear, backwards walk.  So if there are no *merge commits*, and you start Git at the end of a branch, you just see the branch:

```
...--o--o--o--tip   <-- branch
```

But if there are *merge commits*:

```
          C--D
         /    \
...--o--o      G--o--...--tip  <-- branch
         \    /
          E--F
```

then when Git shows `G`, it puts *both `D` and `F`* into its list.  So now you're in the *two commits in the list* situation, and you get into the question of which commit to show first, just like with `git log --all`.

If you use `--first-parent` to force Git not to follow the *other leg* of a merge, this goes away entirely.  Sometimes that's a good thing, and sometimes not.  If you use `--graph` to make Git draw a graph, sometimes that helps, and sometimes the graph gets crazy-complicated.

#### GitHub is sometimes obnoxious

While this has nothing to do with *Git*, it's worth mentioning here that once Git*Hub* has started showing commits in a pull request, Git*Hub* starts doing its own thing with commit-ordering.  It stops using all the normal Git rules, and starts using Git*Hub*'s rules.  Those rules make sense to the GitHub folks, but not so much to many of GitHub's users.  You'll have to talk to the GitHub folks here.

Comment: Thank you, it is really a very detailed explanation about the differences between both regarding how Git treats them. However, maybe I was ambiguous using the word 'semantics'. You made reference to it in your last paragraph (GitHub). What I meant was the 'intention conveyed', and not only how the behaviour of the Git client changes. Could you add something about that? It would make your answer a very thorough one! I'll update my question too. Thank you!

Comment: It's difficult to generalize further: *If* someone (or some software) *does* use the date for something, which date—or dates, since there are the two—it uses, and for what purpose, is up to the one using them. The ordering I mention in the GitHub section is not the order imposed by any dates though. As an experiment I created commits with odd date ordering and put them in a pull request, and they showed up in commit-graph order rather than date order. It seems as though GitHub has some obscure algorithm (which I have been unable to deduce) by which they attempt to "lock" the [continued]

Comment: ... to "lock" the order of commits once people begin commenting on the pull request. If you rebase and rewrite some commits, including changing their graph order, and push that to the ongoing pull request, GitHub sometimes re-arranges them for display to match the original displayed arrangement, rather than the revised graph order. How they do that remains a mystery to me.

Comment: "The ordering I mention in the GitHub section is not the order imposed by any dates though". Yeah, I undertand this part. I asked this because I hoped GitHub had tried a logical use of the dates based in their own undersanding, but nothing imposed. I see now how other criteria could had been considered too. Regarding to the main question, it is a pity, because things can go crazy in those not-so-corner cases. Thanks so much for everything!

Comment: The weird thing is that the GitHub web page says that it orders the commits in a pull request based on the chronological order of *comments made on those commits*, but that's not possible either since you can force-push and have a different set of commits.